# Create MBR Bootable Ubuntu USB from Mac

Tags: ubuntu, mac, installation, mbr, efi

I need to create an ubuntu 16.04 server install USB from a Mac but the computer I'm installing it to only supports booting from MBR USBs.

It seems when I try `dd` it makes it an EFI formatted drive.

How can I take the ubuntu iso and make a MBR install USB? (preferably from terminal)

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu ISO supports MBR and UEFI.

`dd` is fine for the job and the resulting "live USB" will be bootable in any system with BIOS or UEFI.

Alternative method: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0

This alternative method uses a third-party GUI tool, [Etcher for MacOS](https://etcher.io/) (also available for Windows and Linux).

1. Make sure the USB stick is FAT32 formatted; `Disk Utility` (from Applications>Utilities) can be used. Not required for any brand new USB stick up to 32GB.
2. Download and install [Etcher](https://etcher.io/).
3. Run [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) and click "select image" to select the Ubuntu ISO file, then "Select drive" to choose the target drive and finally click the big blue button "Flash!" to burn the ISO into the USB stick.

Note: This should create a bootable USB stick indistinguishable from one done in command line using the `dd` tool.